# list.files pattern argument in R, extended regular expression use

Tags: regex, r

I run

```
  dir.create('./junk_data')
  file.create(paste('./junk_data/QWE',01:12,01:31,2005:2015,'.3',sep=''))
  file.create(paste('./junk_data/RTY',01:12,01:31,2005:2015,'.3',sep=''))
```

and want to list all the files that *begin* with `QWE` and *end* with `2011.3`. I tried

```
list.files('./junk_data/',pattern='QWE....2011.3',full.names=T)
```

and

```
list.files('./junk_data/',pattern='QWE....2011.3',full.names=T,perl=T)
```

but I guess `'.'` doesn't mean one what I think, as I get none of the files I want.

I tried a few tutorials on regex, but no joy.

Comment: 01 is 1 so 01:12 is 1, 2, ... 12. Perhaps you want to do something like `sprintf("%02d", 1:12)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Arun showed in his example, a dot usually means "match any character", so to match a dot you need to escape it: `\\.`.  You can create the pattern most easily with [`glob2rx`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/glob2rx), which uses `*` as a wildcard and matches other characters as though they are fixed.

```
glob2rx("QWE*2011.3")   #"^QWE.*2011\\.3$"
list.files("./junk_data/", pattern = glob2rx("QWE*2011.3"), full.names = TRUE)
```