# R list files with multiple conditions

Tags: r, search, file-listing

I want to list all files in a directory that met certain conditions (date and currency). So with only one condition the argument `pattern` in `list.files` works well:

```
    file.ls <- list.files(path='~/DATA/PiP/Curvas/',pattern='20130801')
```

For multiple conditions I've tried:

```
    file.ls <- list.files(path='~/DATA/PiP/Curvas/',pattern=c('20130801','USD'))
```

But had the same result as the first one. Is there a way to have multiple criteria in `pattern` argument of `list.files`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 Filter(function(x) grepl("USD", x), file.ls)
```

alternatively, you could construct a regular expression for pattern that only matches filenames containing both strings, but that's a wizard's game.

Comment: It works well, but I was hoping to work it out in the `pattern` argument instead of adding another line, but I think yours is the best solution.

Comment: OP didn't ask for a second line to apply to the result of the first ... so it's impossible to do in one line? (not saying it's not the best solution)

Answer (score 47):

```
file.ls <- list.files(path='~/DATA/PiP/Curvas/',pattern="20130801|USD")
```

Comment: This command filters them by currency, the result is a string with the files that contains USD in the name, but does not filter by the date.

Comment: The vertical bar means "or", hence all files are returned which either matches the date and/or the currency. How to filter on both conditions?

Comment: doesn't work, replacing with '&' yields character(0)

Comment: I am also interested on how to use the '&'. grep will do for now though.

Comment: For "&" ("and"), if you know the order, use regex like `20130801.+USD` or `.+20130801.+USD.+`. The `.+` matches any characters in-between (and possibly before/after).

Answer (score 41):

In line with Baptiste and the answer on this post ([list.files pattern argument in R, extended regular expression use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360174/list-files-pattern-argument-in-r-extended-regular-expression-use)), you can use the following expression:

```
file.ls <- list.files(path='~/DATA/PiP/Curvas/',
pattern=glob2rx("*20130801*USD*"))
```

Where `*` is the wildcard.

Answer (score 13):

Here it is:

```
file.ls2 = intersect(list.files(pattern = "20130801"), list.files(pattern = "USD"))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to preserve your `pattern` as a vector (if you are using this in a package function and want to allow the user to specify the pattern as a vector instead of having them use `|` or `*`), you can set it up like this:

```
pattern1 = c('20130801','USD')
file.ls <- list.files(path='~/DATA/PiP/Curvas/', pattern=paste0(pattern1, collapse="|"))
```

This also allows the `pattern1` vector to contain as many elements as you want without having to adjust your code.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use "and" (`&`) rather than "or" (`|`), you can use `.+` within the pattern.

For example:

```
list.files(path='~/DATA/PiP/Curvas/',pattern="20130801.+USD")
```

Answer (score 1):

I interpret you are looking for an `AND` condition. Then I would use:

```
file.ls <- grep(pattern = "(?=.*20130801)(?=.*USD)", 
                x = list.files(path = '~/DATA/PiP/Curvas/'), 
                value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
```

I use this command to return `.tex` files that I have tagged with the `+` sign (a sort of primitive tagging system). For instance, to find files that are tagged as `+neuralnet`, **and** `+style`, **and** `+set`, I use:

```
grep("(?=.*\\+style)(?=.*\\+neuralnet)(?=.*\\+set)",
     list.files("./src", pattern = "*.tex$", full.names = TRUE), 
     value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
```

where `(?=)` is the positive look ahead, and `\\+` is used to escape the `+` sign, which is the character I use for tagging the files. You may add as many `(?=...)` as AND conditions as you need.

My `.tex` files are Latex `TikZ` files. This is a partial list:

```
 [1] "./src/block_diagram-multilayer_perceptron+neuralnet+style+learn.tex"           
 [2] "./src/block_diagram-perceptron+neuralnet+set+learn.tex"                        
 [3] "./src/discriminator+neuralnet+matrix+foreach+style.tex"                        
 [4] "./src/foreach-neural_network-1h+neuralnet.tex"                                 
 [5] "./src/generative_adversarial_network_manual_net+neuralnet.tex"                 
 [6] "./src/generator+neuralnet+matrix.tex"                                          
 [7] "./src/hopfield_auto_net+neuralnet+foreach+scope+learn+style+command.tex"       
 [8] "./src/ml_1h_manual_net+neuralnet+style+matrix+foreach.tex"                     
 [9] "./src/ml_2h_manual_net-color+neuralnet+set+foreach.tex"                        
[10] "./src/ml_a3c_manual_net_arr+neuralnet.tex"                                     
[11] "./src/ml_auto_net_arr+neuralnet+foreach+style+foreach.tex"                     
[12] "./src/ml-auto_net_4h_arr+neuralnet+matrix+foreach+style+scope.tex"             
[13] "./src/ml-auto_net_bias_arr+neuralnet+learn+foreach+def+command+ifnum+style.tex"
[14] "./src/ml-auto_net_color+neuralnet+foreach.tex"                                 
[15] "./src/ml-auto_net_icon+neuralnet+style+foreach+set+function+learn.tex"         
[16] "./src/ml-SVM_manual+neuralnet.tex"                                             
[17] "./src/nn-01-2_summarized+neuralnet+style+learn.tex"                            
[18] "./src/nn-02_auto_net+neuralnet+foreach+pgf+style+learn.tex"                    
[19] "./src/nn-03_auto_net+neuralnet+foreach+style+learn.tex"                        
[20] "./src/nn-04_auto_net+neuralnet+matrix+style+foreach.tex"                       
[21] "./src/nn-05_auto_net_arr+neuralnet+style+foreach+learn.tex"                    
[22] "./src/nn-06_manual_net_color+neuralnet+foreach+style.tex"                      
[23] "./src/nn-08-tkz-berge-01+neuralnet+scope+foreach+pkg.tex"                      
[24] "./src/nn-09_manual_net+neuralnet+foreach+scope.tex"                            
[25] "./src/stacked_blocks+neuralnet+3d+def+pgf+set+style.tex"
```

Then, by using `grep`, with `list.files`, and the *regex* positive look ahead `(?=...)`, I get an effective way of selecting `TikZ` files by purpose or activity I want to work on. The character `+` works fine for tagging, in R and Linux. In Linux I use `find` along with `-and` and `-regex` switches.