# List files with multiple conditions

Tags: r, search, file-listing

I have a set of 16 folders, each of one having sub-folders. I want a code to go into each of those 16 folders, check all the sub-paths and import only those files that fulfill the following conditions:
either they contain "B02.jp2" OR "B03.jp2" OR "B04.jp2" OR "B08.jp2"

Here is a screenshot of the files I want to select

[image]

Here is the code I am using so far:

This one works perfectly but it only uses one condition (B08.jp2$)

```
path <- "my/path/"
path <- list.files(path, recursive = TRUE, full.names = FALSE, pattern =  "B08.jp2$")
```

I have been trying to combine multiple patterns but without success: here are my attempts

Based on: [list.files pattern argument in R, extended regular expression use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360174/list-files-pattern-argument-in-r-extended-regular-expression-use)

```
path <- "my/path/"
path <- list.files(path, recursive = TRUE, full.names = FALSE, pattern =  glob2rx("B08.jp2$*B03.jp2$"))
path<-character(0)
```

Based on: [R list files with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028225/r-list-files-with-multiple-conditions)

```
path <- "my/path/"
path <- list.files(path, recursive = TRUE, full.names = FALSE, pattern = "B08.jp2$ | B03.jp2$")
path<-character(0)
```

-- EDIT --

I have change my data slightly and would like to import them in a different way. My files are now called:

```
B02_10m.jp2
B03_10m.jp2
B04_10m.jp2
B08_10m.jp2

B05_20m.jp2
B06_20m.jp2
B07_20m.jp2
B8A_20m.jp2
B11_20m.jp2
B12_20m.jp2
```

They are located in different sub-folders. That's way I am using `recursive=TRUE`.

I have trying with the following options to combine the conditions but it's not working.

```
S2 <- "my/path"
S2 <- list.files(S2, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern =  "B0[2348]_10m.jp2$ | B(0[567]_20m)|(1[12]_20m)|(8A_20m).jp2$")

S2 <- "my/path"
S2 <- list.files(S2, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern =  "B0[2348]_10m | B(0[567]_20m)|(1[12]_20m)|(8A_20m).jp2$")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
list.files(path, recursive = TRUE, full.names = FALSE, 
           pattern = "B0[2348].jp2$")
```

The pattern accepts a regular expression.

Comment: Totally works, much easier than the solutions I was trying! Thanks a lot

Comment: Small comment, what if I want to import also the files that end with B11, B12 and B8A. I have tried to use `"B0[2348].jp2$ | B11.jp2$ | B12.jp2$ | B8A.jp2$"` but is not working

Comment: Having the following error message: `object X not found`. From `?grep', I see that I have to specify the path where the conditions have to be matched. Is that correct?

Comment: @GCGM ah, sorry, of course you have to put that regex into the list.files function. It should then be  `list.files(path, recursive = TRUE, full.names = FALSE, pattern = "B((0[2348])|(1[12])|(8A)).jp2$")`

Comment: Thanks again :) have to learn more about those logical patterns

Comment: I have updated my question to ask for a related issue

Comment: @GCGM, please ask a new question. The original question has been answered and is closed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694848/list-files-with-multiple-conditions-part2