# List files with multiple conditions part2

Tags: r, search, file-listing

I have the following rasters and would like to import them in R. My files are now called:

```
B02_10m.jp2
B03_10m.jp2
B04_10m.jp2
B08_10m.jp2

B05_20m.jp2
B06_20m.jp2
B07_20m.jp2
B8A_20m.jp2
B11_20m.jp2
B12_20m.jp2
```

They are located in different sub-folders. That's way I am using `recursive=TRUE`

I have trying with the following options to combine the conditions but it's not working.

```
 S2 <- "my/path"
S2 <- list.files(S2, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern =  "B0[2348]_10m.jp2$ | B(0[567]_20m)|(1[12]_20m)|(8A_20m).jp2$")

S2 <- "my/path"
S2 <- list.files(S2, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern =  "B0[2348]_10m | B(0[567]_20m)|(1[12]_20m)|(8A_20m).jp2$")
```

Comment: try `B((0[2348]_10m)|(((0[567])|(1[12])|(8A))_20m)).jp2$`

Comment: Thanks again, still checking your parenthesis sequence but it's working! If you put it as an answer, I'll mark it :)

Comment: You can write up an answer after you understood the sequence

Comment: @docendodiscimus, is it possible to define a variable - e.g. `var<-"B((0[2348]_10m)|((0[567])_20m)).jp2$"` -  and then use it in `pattern` - e.g. `, pattern=var`. So far, I have tried and it seems it is not

Comment: yes of course, that is possible

Comment: Okay, I was missing `c(" ")`. For readers, `var<-c("B((0[2348]_10m)|((0[567])_20m)).jp2$")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For other users and based on @docendo discimus answer, here is the idea to combine different conditions when listing files as in my case. My conditions are based on the numbers that are following the letter B so:

```
pattern="B( here we need to write the conditions).jp2$
```

First, we will set the condition to import the files B02_10m, B03_10m, B04_10m, B08_10m

```
patter="B(FIRST CONDITION OR SECOND CONDITION).jp2$
pattern="B((0[2348]_10m)|SECOND CONDITION).jp2$
```

Second, we will import the files B05_20m, B06_20m, B07_20m, B8A_20m, B11_20m, B12_20m. In this case, we have to combine several sub-conditions because the pattern changes from e.g.: 02 to 11, 12 and 8A

First we write the code for 5, 6 and 7

```
pattern="B((0[2348]_10m)|((0[567])_20m)).jp2$
```

Then we add the code for bands 11 and 12

```
pattern="B((0[2348]_10m)|((0[567])|(1[12])_20m)).jp2$
```

Then, the code for 8A

```
pattern="B((0[2348]_10m)|(((0[567])|(1[12])|(8A))_20m)).jp2$
```

Hope it's clear

Comment: You should not use spaces I guess

Comment: The point is that if you point some spaces in the patterns for readability, you are changing the actual patterns and they might not work