# R - Use Glob Pattern to Extract text files from multiple directories

Tags: r, glob, fs, ls

I'm trying to work out a way of extracting text files from multiple directories using `fs:dir_ls` and `vroom`.

The directory structure is essentially `M:/instrument/project/experiment/measurements/time_stamp/raw_data/files*.txt`.

Ideally, I want to be able to define the path to the experiment level then let the pattern take care of the rest, for example -

`fs::dir_ls(path="M:/instrument/project/", glob = "experiment_*/2021-04-11*/raw_data/files*.txt", invert = TRUE, recurse = TRUE)`,

So I'm reading in all the .txt files across multiple experiment directories in one go, however, when I try this approach it returns all the files from the project level rather than those from the specific folders described by the pattern.

I've looked through the other SO questions on the topic covered here: [Pattern matching using a wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823503/pattern-matching-using-a-wildcard), [R list files with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028225/r-list-files-with-multiple-conditions), [list.files pattern argument in R, extended regular expression use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360174/list-files-pattern-argument-in-r-extended-regular-expression-use), and [grep using a character vector with multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-using-a-character-vector-with-multiple-patterns), but haven't been able to apply them to my particular problem.

Any help is appreciated, I realise the answer is likely staring me in the face, I just need help seeing it.

Thanks

Comment: If you want files from `raw_data` folder can you try ? `list.files('M:/instrument/project/experiment/measurements/time_stamp/raw_data/', pattern = 'files.*\\.txt')`

Comment: Thanks, however, when I try this it returns an empty character.

Comment: What is the complete path of the files that you want to select?

Comment: The full path to one of the files is `M:/Operetta/LED_Wound/operetta_export/plate_variability[540]/robot_seed_wide_plate_1[1614]/2021-05-10T113438+0100[1764]/SC_data/arpe19_10x_hoescht_h2dcfda_ints_morpho_SC[47280].result.A1[46991].Population - vaid_nuclei[0].txt`

Comment: and it's the arpe19[...].txt file that I'm wanting to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following with `list.files` :

```
files <- list.files('M:/Operetta/LED_Wound/operetta_export/plate_variability[540]/robot_seed_wide_plate_1[1614]/2021-05-10T113438+0100[1764]/SC_data', pattern = 'arpe19*\\.txt')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this approach works but only searches one directory for the files when Ideally I wish to read files from multiple directories i.e. `robot_plate_1-3`. This way, I don't have to redefine the path starting after `plate_variability[540]`, including the timestamps, for each batch of files. So I need a glob/regex pattern that captures the preceding directories, something like ``~/robot_seed_wide_plate_*`/2021-05-//*/SC_Data/arpe19//*.txt``.

Comment: @DrBalticYaldie Add `recursive = TRUE` i.e `files <- list.files(..., pattern = ..., recursive = TRUE)`